# i'm doing test in laravel whene run command php artisan test see this error

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-testing

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_testing> PHP artisan test
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on the Windows platform.

RUNS  Tests\Unit\AccountantHelperTest
• it can find profit

Tests:  3 pending

FAIL  Tests\Unit\AccountantHelperTest
✕ it can find profit

Tests:  1 failed, 2 pending

Error

Class 'App\AccountantHelper' not found

at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_testing\tests\Unit\AccountantHelperTest.php:16
12|      * @test
13|      */
14|  public function it_can_find_profit()
15|   {

> 16|           $profit= AccountantHelper::findProfit(100);
> 17|           $this->assertEquals(10,$profit);
> 18|
> 19|   }
> 20| }

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_testing\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:1472
Tests\Unit\AccountantHelperTest::it_can_find_profit()

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_testing\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:1092
PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::runTest()

AccountantHelper is a class in the folder app

```
<?php
namespace App;


class AccountantHelper
{

function Profit($amount)
{

    $profitPercent =10;
    return $profitPercent * $amount / 100 ;
}

}
```

AccountantHelperTest is file in tests/unit

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;
use App\AccountantHelper;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AccountantHelperTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test  */
  function it_can_find_profit()
  {
          $Profit= AccountantHelper::Profit(100);
          $this->assertEquals(10,$Profit);

  }
}
```

Comment: add the code to your question. the AccountantHelperTest.php and the AccountantHelper.php

Comment: "_Class 'App\AccountantHelper' not found_" Did you `use` it in your test?

Comment: sure
i will add my code in question

Comment: `Profit` function is not static so you need to make a `new AccountantHelper` to be able to use it (or make it static). [static keyword in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: I certainly did that, but the same problem appeared

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShahin update your question with your attempt in making the method static (or creating an instance). Also can you share your composer.json?

Comment: thanks, i'm solved it

Answer (score 1):

Your `Profit` method in `AccountantHelper` class is not static. Your code should be like this:

```php
class AccountantHelper
{
    public static function Profit($amount)
    {
        $profitPercent =10;
        return $profitPercent * $amount / 100 ;
    }
}
```

Also, if that was an Eloquent Model and you had many queries on there you could use [`scope`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: i'mI certainly did that, but the same problem appeared

Comment: why    Class 'App\AccountantHelper' not found ??

Comment: Are you sure about `AccountatnHelper` path? is it in the `app/` directory?